# Update Android database from CSV file

Tags: android, database, sqlite, csv

I'm developing an application which would download the CSV file and populate the DB table with the CSV's data.

The problem is that CSV file will be modified every hour and my app will have to update the DB according to the changes.

I don't know which the changes will be - a row is deleted/added or a record is changed.

What will be the best practice in this case? Should I drop the table and create it again when the new CSV is downloaded? Or will it better to compare existing values with the new ones and make the necessary changes?

Comment: Well try them both. Why didnt you already?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem can be solved if you put an updateTime column in your table and when you import data from csv everytime, you just perform the update with:

```
                 int rowsEffected = database.update(...);
```

if rowsEffected>0, you perform insert. Everytime you insert or update you need to put the updated datetime in the updateTime column and also in a sharedpreference. Next, when you get the data from the csv file next hour, just check the datetime from sharedpreference and delete every column that is not marked with the datatime in the updateTime column, as they were not present in the previous csv and continue the process of insert and update. I would not drop and recreate because drop and recreate resembles to clean start but here you are just manipulating data.